# remove first and last blank line <p>&nbsp</p> which is created by ckediter using php

Tags: php, regex, blank-line

i have a string $str

> $str="
> `<p>&nbsp;</p>`
>
> `<p>&nbsp;</p>`
>
> `<p> hi </p>`
>
> `<p>hello how are you</p>`
>
> `<p>&nbsp;</p>`
>
> `<p>&nbsp;</p>`
>
> `<p>hello how are you</p>`
>
> `<p>&nbsp;</p>`
>
> `<p>&nbsp;</p>";`

This was generated by ckediter 
The string is random based on the input,
I want to remove the first and the last blank line (`<p>&nbsp</p>`)

I need the output like :-

> `<p> hi </p>`
> `<p>hello how are you</p>`
> `<p>&nbsp;</p>`
> `<p>&nbsp;</p>`
> `<p>hello how are you</p>`

The answer should do the action of  trim() function in php 
Is there any way in ckediter to trim it ??
or regular expression?

Comment: The second parameter of the `trim()` function allows you to specify what to trim...

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, this regex would do the job:

```
$result = preg_replace('%\s*<p\b[^>]*>\s*&nbsp;?\s*</p>\s*%si', '', $subject);
```

If you don't want it to trim blank space before or after each `<p>&nbsp;</p>` then delete the first or the last `\s*`. Also, I've added in an optional semicolon, because `&nbsp` is often (usually?) `&nbsp;`. This regex will match either.